# Legendre symbol simplification

Tags: number-theory

I saw a simplification using the Legendre symbol which said $$\left(\dfrac{19}{29}\right) = \left(\dfrac{10}{19}\right) = \left(\dfrac{2}{19}\right) \cdot \left(\dfrac{5}{19}\right) = -1.$$ My question is how did they get $\left(\dfrac{19}{29}\right) = \left(\dfrac{10}{19}\right)$ and finally that $\left(\dfrac{2}{19}\right) \cdot \left(\dfrac{5}{19}\right) = -1$?

Comment: Quadratic reciprocity and multiplicativity of the Legendre symbol.

Comment: As an alternative, $$ \left (\frac{19}{29} \right)= \left( \frac{10}{29} \right) = \left( \frac{-3}{29}\right)= -1$$ since $29$ is not a prime of the form $3k+1$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question

$$
\left(\dfrac{19}{29}\right) = \left(\dfrac{29}{19}\right)
 = \left(\dfrac{10}{19}\right)
$$
since $29$ is $1$ mod $4$.

For the second, 
$$
\left(\dfrac{5}{19}\right) = 
\left(\dfrac{19}{5}\right) = 
\left(\dfrac{-1}{5}\right) = 1
$$
since $5$ is $1$ mod $4$
and
$$
\left(\dfrac{2}{19}\right) = -1
$$
because $19$ is $3$ mod $8$. (http://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/classroom-capsules-and-notes/the-quadratic-character-of-2)

Answer (score 1):

This seems a combination of quadratic reciprocity and the Legendre formula.

The Legendre formula states that $\left(\dfrac{a}{p}\right) \equiv a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\mod p$, giving $\left(\dfrac{2}{19}\right) = -1$ and $\left(\dfrac{5}{19}\right) = 1$. These give the second equality. (Since 19 isn't that large, it's quite possible to do determine by hand if 2 or 5 are quadratic residues).

The quadratic reciprocity law states that $\left(\dfrac{p}{q}\right)\left(\dfrac{q}{p}\right) = (-1)^{{\frac{p-1}{2}}{\frac{q-1}{2}}}$. Since $\left({\dfrac{29}{19}}\right) = \left({\dfrac{10}{19}}\right)$, the first equality you asked for follows. (Notice that since $\left(\dfrac{p}{q}\right)$ and its reciprocal are $\pm1$, dividing or multiplying by one of them yields the same result.)

Comment: I am wondering why it turns out that $14$ is the least such power of $19$ such that $19$ to a power is $-1$ modulo $29$. We have $19^{\frac{29-1}{2}} = 19^{14}\equiv -1 \pmod{29}$. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite follow you. Any power of $19$ is equivalent to $0$ modulo 19, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant modulo $29$.

Comment: I'm not sure I know about any reason why it should be the least power. What we do know for sure, thanks to Fermat's little theorem and due to the fact that $29$ is prime, is that $a^{28}\equiv 1\mod 29$ for all $a$. As a result $a^{14} \equiv \pm 1\mod 29$ for all $a$. It could just as well have been the case that $7$ would've fulfilled the requirement you mention, since it's a diviser of $28$ as well.